# Socket.io app does not work on phone client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I have a socket.io app that works perfectly on chrome, safari and opera, with notifications made using push.js.

```
</head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Nickersoft/push.js/master/push.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          var socket = io();
          var username = prompt("What's your name?");
          var notification = new Audio('https://cdn.rawgit.com/InfiniaPress/Passenger-Pigeon/master/assets/notification.mp3');

          if(username){
              socket.emit('connection info', username);
          }

          function send(message) {
              $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(message));
          }

          socket.on('user add', function(usr){
              send(usr.username + " has joined.");
          });


          $('form').submit(function(){
              socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
              $('#m').val('');
              return false;
          });

          socket.on('user left', function(usr){
              send(usr.username + " has disconnected.");
          })

          socket.on('chat message', function(msg, usr){
              Push.create('Passenger Pigeon', {
                body: usr.username + ": " + msg,
                icon: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/InfiniaPress/Passenger-Pigeon/master/assets/pigeon-final.png",
                timeout: 4000,
                onClick: function () {
                    window.focus();
                    this.close();
                },
                vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]
              });
              notification.play();
              send(usr.username + ": " + msg);
          });

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is my client side.

```
var express = require('express'); // Get the module
var app = express(); // Create express by calling the prototype in var express
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
// Import events module
var events = require('events');
// Create an eventEmitter object
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var config = require('./config.json');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/view/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg, {username: socket.username});
  });
  socket.on('connection info', function(usr){
    socket.username = usr;
    io.emit('user add', {username: usr});
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('Passenger Pigeon >> a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        socket.broadcast.emit('user left', {
            username: socket.username,
        });
        console.log('Passenger Pigeon >> user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || config.port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + config.port);
});
```

^that is my server side.

When I open the app on mobile the [username] has joined prints out, but all messages do NOT appear on the client side. Other computers receive the messages. Why is this so?

Comment: what phone are you using?

Comment: It will not work for iphone: https://github.com/Nickersoft/push.js/issues/34